# Call Controller of an autoplayed video in ViewController

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avkit

I have set it up so that when a ViewController is displayed, a video starts automatically and at the end it switches to a different ViewController.

The problem is that if the app is put in the background while viewing it, the video freezes and you have to restart the application.

I thought about setting the classic pause / play controllers to appear when you press the screen so you can continue watching, but I don't know how to do that.

Or do you have another solution to prevent the video from freezing?

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class View8BaController: UIViewController {

    func setupAVPlayer() {

        let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "8B-A", withExtension: "mp4") // Get video url
        let avAssets = AVAsset(url: videoURL!) // Create assets to get duration of video.
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!) // Create avPlayer instance
        let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer) // Create avPlayerLayer instance
        avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds // Set bounds of avPlayerLayer
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer) // Add avPlayerLayer to view's layer.
        
        avPlayer.play() // Play video

        // Add observer for every second to check video completed or not,
        // If video play is completed then redirect to desire view controller.
        avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 1) , queue: .main) { [weak self] time in

            if time == avAssets.duration {
                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SCENA7") as! SCENA7ViewController
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.setupAVPlayer()  // Call method to setup AVPlayer & AVPlayerLayer to play video
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried telling the video to play in the sceneDelegate?

add to the class, right above func setupAVPlayer(),

```
var avPlayer: AvPlayer!
```

then in your sceneDelegate outside any functions

```
let view8Ba = View8BaController()
```

to create an instance of the view controller. Then you can access the properties in the following:

```
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    if view8Ba.viewIfLoaded?.window != nil {
     view8Ba.avPlayer.play()
    }
 }
```

This will tell your video to start playing again when the app comes back from the background.

If you want to add a play/pause when you tap the screen you can add a tap gesture recognizer and another view to the current view controller and set the background to clear (in storyboard drag the new view to the white bar on top of the view controller)

then call

```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        pauseScreenView.frame = View8BaController.bounds
    }
```

This tells the new view you added where to be on the viewController.

In the IBAction of the tap gesture recognizer

```
@IBAction func screenTapped(_ sender: Any) {

View8BaController.addSubview(pauseScreenView)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
    self.pauseScreenView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

This adds the new view to the top of the viewController and then removes it after 10 seconds.

In that new view you can add a button that will play/pause your video

```
@IBAction func pauseVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if avPlayer.timeControlStatus == .playing {
        avPlayer.pause()
        pauseButton.setImage(playImage, for: .normal)
    }else {
        avPlayer.play()
        pauseButton.setImage(pauseImage, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first option that might suit me anyway.
But if I enter your code in SceneDelegate I get the error:

Instance member 'avPlayer' cannot be used on type 'View8BaController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: Sorry. You need to add an instance of the view controller to be able to access the properties. I edited above.

Comment: Thanks for the change.
I did as you indicated, but on opening the application crashes after 1 second with the following error:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value. 
-------
the error occurs in Scenedelegate.swift in the string:                                             

func sceneWillEnterForeground (_ scene: UIScene) {
         // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
         // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
         view8Ba.avPlayer.play ()

     }

Comment: You need to check that the view8Ba view is an active view. Otherwise it is trying to play the video that was never instantiated when the app comes to the foreground. See new edit

Comment: I tried to insert the revised string in scene delegate but:                                                  the `if view8Ba? .window! = nil { ` ----  gives me an error ------- Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'View8BbController' ; Remove '?' and ----  Value of type 'View8BbController' has no member 'window

Comment: oops. forgot the .viewIfLoaded.

Comment: I tested the app, but nothing doesn't change the result.
When the app comes back from the background it shows the frozen video and does not restart or continue.

Comment: for the moment I "solved" by inserting an "else" condition that if the video is not finished to force it to continue even in the background simply by reusing the "player.Play ()" function

Thanks anyway @Jwoodland